# Down power line/sewer attention

Tags: electrical

Due to an accident a power line/pole was knocked down one house down. As part of the repair attention and gravel like stuff was placed around the sewer grate in the street in front of my house.  Why is attention being paid to the sewer with a downed power line/pole?

Comment: What sense are you using "attention" in when you say *"As part of the repair attention and gravel like stuff was placed"*?

Comment: not a home improvement question ... it is off topic here ... probably a leaking transformer

Comment: Thought about just going over and talking to the repair guys.  Only they know what it is about.

Answer (score 6):

If the there was a transformer on the pole, and/or the vehicle was leaking, oil absorbents (and possibly other ones for antifreeze, etc.) would be deployed to prevent transformer oil or car fluids from contaminating the storm sewers and the waterways the storm sewers lead to.

It's much less effort to contain such spills at the source than to clean them up when they've spread over miles/kilometers of waterways and wetlands.